# Php, how to program "crontasks" if server doesnt support this?

Tags: php, concurrency

So, site is on a production server which doesnt support crontasks. And I want to delete invalid password requests, not used discounts, anything which are over a "deadline". Its not problem they are not precise, its not a problem if a password request is valid for 24 hours and its 24 hours and 58 second (so they can be in late for some seconds).

Currently Im doing it like that:

```
private function thisMethodRunsAtEveryRequests()
{
    if (rand(1,100) == 1)
    {
        do cleaning SQLs
    }
}
```

still, there are problems when it triggers at the same time.

Comment: Just use transactions or some other synchronization mechanism like lock files. You should do this anyway, even when using proper cron tools.

Comment: that's essentially how php's session garbage collector works. it has a random chance of being invoked on EVERY request the server handles. if the site's entirely idle, no requests are made, and there's by definition 0 chance of the collector being invoked. your site would have the same problem.

Comment: Try some kind of synchronising. Maybe keep tracking in Redis every active cron or something.

Comment: External service that call your site (a page) every tot time?

Comment: Maybe I can use the visitor's IP to avoid collision, or is there better option to identify him?

Answer (score 1):

If you can do the cron task to other server, you could do the following:

- Create a "website.com/cron.php" file, which does what ever you want it to do
- Create a cron task to other server which will load the **website.com/cron.php** via curl, like: `* * * * * curl http://www.website.com/cron.php > /dev/null 2>&1`

If not, then you could write the last time your script performed this "cron task" into a file/database and check it on every page load when was the last time it was performed and if the difference between `time()` and last time is enough, run the task again.